# Get Ubuntu version number only with bash

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I execute command `cat /etc/os-release` in order to get info like

```
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="18.04 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 18.04 LTS"
VERSION_ID="18.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=bionic
UBUNTU_CODENAME=bionic
```

I want to get only **18.04** from `VERSION_ID`

I tried like

```
cat /etc/os-release | grep VERSION_ID=
```

which returns

```
VERSION_ID="18.04"
```

I don't know how to take that version number. Can advice me how to do that ?

Comment: How about `lsb_release -sr` in Bash/Terminal?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Source it and you can access the variable directly:

```
. /etc/os-release
echo "$VERSION_ID"
```

Answer (score 4):

Using `lsb_release` is an ideal way to access distribution information. To get only the version, use:

```
lsb_release -sr
```

If `lsb_release` isn't installed on your system (if I recall correctly) do:

```
sudo apt-get install lsb-core
```

Comment: Should be provided with the installation of the OS version already. Didn't think my comment was worth an answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

You may use `awk`:

```
awk -F= '$1 == "VERSION_ID" {gsub(/"/, "", $2); print $2}' /etc/os-release
```

```
18.04
```